Battery for Sony C-74 mic
This lovely historical hypercardioid mic uses Eveready 117 standard (says manual) or H-7D E-177 TR-177 or equivalent (says mic body).
The only "replacement" battery is _Exell S177_¹, but that's not cheap and I'd have to pay insanely high S&H to Europe.
Anything else that worked for you my European fellows?
¹ 10.5 V, 150 mAh, Length: 1.91", Diameter: 0.55"

This might be a possibility - https://foxvideo.co.uk/c74/

Mic works perfectly with 12V "photo" battery (Westinghouse A23, Varta V23GA) and a physical extension - a big fat screw for ¢2.
